# Array reduce sum with null values

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can't get array reduce to work:

```
var labels  = ["MetricLinuxMemory","memCached","memTotalFree","MetricLinuxCPU","CpuRawSystem","memTotalSwap"];
var columns = [{values:[12,1,2,23,null,2]},{values:[12,null,2]},{values:[12,1,2]},{values:[12,1,2]},{values:[12,1,2]},{values:[12,1,2]}];

var data = {};      //Selected Performance data

// Loop through labels
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {   

    var label = labels[i];

    //Search for calculated vlaue (Metric)
    if(label.includes("Metric")){

        //Create property in data object
        data[label] = {};

        var metric  = data[label];
            metric.samples = [];
            metric.sum  = 1;

        //Get appropriate column
        var values = columns[i].values;

        // Loop through values
        for (var ii = 0; ii < values.length; ii++) {    

            //Convert to numeric
            var value = parseInt(values[ii], 10);

            //Push to data
            metric.samples.push(value);
            metric.sum = metric.samples.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);

        }


    }
}
```

Desired output would be:

```
{
    "MetricLinuxMemory": {
        "samples": [
            ...
            23,
            null,
            ...
        ],
        "sum": 40
    },
    ...
}
```

However i can not seem to get one sum to work. And get null in MetricLinuxMemory instead. Shouldn't parseInt take care of the null input and convert it for example to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parseInt still return NaN, not 0. Just use:

```
var value = values[ii] == null? 0 : parseInt(values[ii], 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't parseInt take care of the null input and convert it for example to 0?

On the contrary. `parseInt` converts `null` to `NaN` (after having it converted to the string `"null"`). You should not use `parseInt` on anything else but strings!

If you had just left it out, it would even have worked, since addition of a number with `null` causes it to be coerced to `0`. However, if you want to be explicit about it, just put the `samples.push(value)` statement inside an `if (value != null)` or `if (typeof value == "number")` statement.